# Adding multiple files with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have a form in a page called `gallery.php`, and the code is the following:

```
<form action="upload_image.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div align="center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="image_alt"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> &nbspSeleziona immagini</a></div>
            <input id="image" name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" required="required" style="margin-left:50%;" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn_add_img"></label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div align="center">
                <button id="btn_add_img" name="btn_add_img" class="btn btn-primary">Carica</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Next, i have the page called upload_image.php with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$where = dirname(__FILE__);
include($where . "/config/db.php");
$categoria_img = '1';
$id_album = '1';

// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {   
    $nome_file_temporaneo = $file["tmp_name"];
    $nome_file_vero = $file["name"];
    $tipo_file = $file["type"];
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tipo_file);$i++) {
        echo "<br>Nome:" . $nome_file_temporaneo[$i]."<br>";
        $dati_file = file_get_contents($nome_file_temporaneo[$i]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO images (category_id,image_big,image_type,id_album) values (:categoria_img,:data,:img_type,:id_album)";
        echo "<br>".$query;
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(":categoria_img", $categoria_img, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":data", $dati_file, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":img_type", $tipo_file[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_album", $id_album, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that `upload_image.php` doesn't show any error..and anything be stored in the database after passing file by the form in `gallery.php` page..could someone help me?

***UPDATE***

> **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]:** Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\castellazzo_theme\PHP Version\upload_image.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\castellazzo_theme\PHP Version\upload_image.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\castellazzo_theme\PHP Version\upload_image.php on line 31

Comment: *"doesn't show any error"* - That's because you're not checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: You never bother checking for errors. You simply assuming nothing could ever fail. And why are you using addslashes() when you're using prepared statements+placeholders? You'd essentially be double-escaping.

Comment: you can delete your comment, I've made an edit to your question. In the future, please add any errors/warnings/notices in your question, rather than in comments. Edit: ah, you overwrote mine, ok. no problemo

Comment: I'll add error, warnings etc in the question, and sorry for the overwrite, i think we were updating the question on the same time

Comment: someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bindParam(":data", $dati_file, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Should be

```
$stmt->bindParam(":data", $dati_file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)

But you should be storing location of image rather than storing it a  Blob.

Comment: nothing has changed with PARAM_LOB, nothing happens in the database